# How to not copy an attribute in the output of XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I want to transform the one XML message into other. My input message currently contains some empty elements with attributes @nil=ture value. What I want is that these elements should be created empty but without the nill attribute. Please see below my current progess:

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <collection>
        <row>
            <nr>A00</nr>
            <type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
        </row>
        <row>
            <nr>A01</nr>
            <type>mash</type>
        </row>
    </collection>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='collection']">
        <jsonArray>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml-multiple?&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='row']">
                <jsonObject>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="node() except @nil" />
                </jsonObject>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </jsonArray>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsonArray>
   <?xml-multiple?>
   <jsonObject>
      <nr>A00</nr>
      <type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
   </jsonObject>
   <jsonObject>
      <nr>A01</nr>
      <type>mash</type>
   </jsonObject>
</jsonArray>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsonArray>
   <?xml-multiple?>
   <jsonObject>
      <nr>A00</nr>
      <type/>
   </jsonObject>
   <jsonObject>
      <nr>A01</nr>
      <type>mash</type>
   </jsonObject>
</jsonArray>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<xsl:copy-of select="node() except @nil" />` you are copying the child elements of the current `row`, which will copy them without changes. The `except @nil` won't do what you expect because it will be looking for attributes called `@nil` on the current `row` element (and the attribute you are looking for is `@xsi:nil` anyway.

Instead replace `xsl:copy-of` with `xsl:apply-templates` and add the identity template to your XSLT (with a slight tweak to remove namespace declarations).

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you just need a template to ignore `xsl:type`

```
    <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil" />

    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='collection']">
        <jsonArray>
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple" />
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='row']">
                <jsonObject>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </jsonObject>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </jsonArray>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Do note you should really use `xsl:processing-instruction` to create processing instructions).